# workmanager throws errors in weblogic.xml

Tags: weblogic, workmanagers

I saw no post related to the problem I am facing. I recently added work-manager under weblogic.xml which I think is a DTD file.
But as soon as I add this tag into weblogic.xml, I get the following error:

> The content of element type
>   "weblogic-web-app" must match
>   "(description?,weblogic-version?,security-role-
>   assignment*,run-as-role-assignment*,reference-descriptor?,session-descriptor?,jsp-descriptor?,auth-
>   filter?,container-descriptor?,charset-params?,virtual-directory-mapping*,url-match-
>   map?,preprocessor*,preprocessor-mapping*,security-permission?,context-root?,wl-dispatch-policy?,servlet-
>   descriptor*,init-as*,destroy-as*)".

Following is a sample weblogic.xml where I made the change:

I am able to successfully deploy my code to weblogic. But I could not test the flow yet. I am on it now. But I am worried if my code changes actually work because I am getting this error.

Am I missing adding any reference to the work-manager?

[Documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs90/webapp/weblogic_xml.html#1063118) shows:

The work-manager element is a sub-element of the `<weblogic-web-app>` element. You can define the following elements within the work-manager element.

Let me know if I missed anything here.

Comment: Are you trying to create an application-scoped Work Manager or are you trying to reference one that is already created?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a valid example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<weblogic-web-app
xmlns="http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/90"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/90 http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/90/weblogic-web-app.xsd">

    <wl-dispatch-policy>MyWorkManager</wl-dispatch-policy>

    <work-manager>
        <name>MyWorkManager</name>
        <min-threads-constraint>
            <name>MyWorkManager-MinThreads</name>
            <count>50</count>
        </min-threads-constraint>
        <max-threads-constraint>
            <name>MyWorkManager-MaxThreads</name>
            <count>50</count>
        </max-threads-constraint>
    </work-manager>
</weblogic-web-app>
```